# Bootstrap modal to confirm deletion

Tags: django, bootstrap-4

When I loop over my images I have an icon that you can click to delete the image. Instead I'd like to have a modal pop up to confirm the deletion. The only problem is I don't want to repeate the code for the modal for each image. I need a way to pass the image id to the modal.

I was thinking I could pass the id in through an `onClick` but I'm not sure that will work with the Bootstrap modal.

**Here's how I'm currently deleting:**

```
{% for image in images %}
  <img src="{{image.image.url}}">
  <form method="POST" action="{% url 'products:delete_image>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button type="submit" rel="tooltip" title="Remove">
      <i class="material-icons">close</i>
    </button>
  </form>
{% endfor %}
```

**Here's the modal code I'd like to integrate**

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assign a click handler to the button inside each form and give each form a unique id. For example, give all the form buttons a class like `confirm-delete`. Assign a click handler (this is jQuery but you could also use vanilla JS)...

```
$('.confirm-delete').on('click', function(e) {
    // prevent form submit
    e.preventDefault();
    
    // get the current image/form id
    var id = $(this).attr("id")
    
    // assign the current id to the modal and show the modal
    $('#myModal').data('id', id).modal('show');
})
```

Then inside the modal, have a button that actually performs the delete using the id that is passed through `data`...

```
$('#btnDelete').click(function() {
    // handle deletion here
    var id = $('#myModal').data('id');
    
    // submit the form
    $('form'+id).submit();
    
    // if needed, remove deleted image 
    // and form from DOM
    $('#img'+id).remove();
    $('#form'+id).remove();
    
    // hide modal
    $('#myModal').modal('hide');
})
```

[Demo](https://codeply.com/p/3FUnS5SBCE)